# Why does SQL Server "Compute Scalar" when I SELECT a persisted computed column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, execution-plan

The three `SELECT` statements in this code

```
USE [tempdb];
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE dbo.persist_test (
      id            INT NOT NULL
    , id5           AS (id * 5)
    , id5p          AS (id * 5) PERSISTED
);

INSERT INTO dbo.persist_test (id)
VALUES (1), (2), (3);

SELECT id
FROM dbo.persist_test;

SELECT id5
FROM dbo.persist_test;

SELECT id5p
FROM dbo.persist_test;

DROP TABLE dbo.persist_test;
```

generate this plan:

[image: execution plan]

Why does the final `SELECT`, which is selecting a persisted value, generate a [Compute Scalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178082%28SQL.105%29.aspx) operator?

Comment: See @SqlKiwi's answer here: [Why does the Execution Plan include a user-defined function call for a computed column that is persisted?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5998217/73226). In your query the output column list from the table is only `[tempdb].[dbo].[persist_test].id` and it calculates the value despite being persisted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just to summarise the experimental findings in the comments this seems to be an edge case that occurs when you have two computed columns in the same table, one `persisted` and one not persisted and they both have the same definition.

In the plan for the query

```
SELECT id5p
FROM dbo.persist_test;
```

The table scan on `persist_test` emits only the `id` column. The next compute scalar along multiplies that by 5 and outputs a column called `id5` despite the fact that this column is not even referenced in the query. The final compute scalar along takes the value of `id5` and outputs that as a column called `id5p`.

Using the trace flags explained in [Query Optimizer Deep Dive – Part 2](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/04/28/query-optimizer-deep-dive-part-2.aspx) (disclaimer: these trace flags are undocumented/unsupported) and looking at the query

```
SELECT id5,
       id5p,
       ( id * 5 )
FROM   dbo.persist_test 
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 3604, QUERYTRACEON 8606);
```

Gives the output

**Tree Before Project Normalization**

```
LogOp_Project

    LogOp_Get TBL: dbo.persist_test dbo.persist_test TableID=1717581157 TableReferenceID=0 IsRow: COL: IsBaseRow1002 

    AncOp_PrjList 

        AncOp_PrjEl QCOL: [tempdb].[dbo].[persist_test].id5

            ScaOp_Arithmetic x_aopMult

                ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [tempdb].[dbo].[persist_test].id

                ScaOp_Const TI(int,ML=4) XVAR(int,Not Owned,Value=5)

        AncOp_PrjEl QCOL: [tempdb].[dbo].[persist_test].id5p

            ScaOp_Arithmetic x_aopMult

                ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [tempdb].[dbo].[persist_test].id

                ScaOp_Const TI(int,ML=4) XVAR(int,Not Owned,Value=5)

        AncOp_PrjEl COL: Expr1004 

            ScaOp_Arithmetic x_aopMult

                ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [tempdb].[dbo].[persist_test].id

                ScaOp_Const TI(int,ML=4) XVAR(int,Not Owned,Value=5)
```

**Tree After Project Normalization**

```
LogOp_Project

    LogOp_Get TBL: dbo.persist_test dbo.persist_test TableID=1717581157 TableReferenceID=0 IsRow: COL: IsBaseRow1002 

    AncOp_PrjList 

        AncOp_PrjEl QCOL: [tempdb].[dbo].[persist_test].id5

            ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [tempdb].[dbo].[persist_test].id5

        AncOp_PrjEl QCOL: [tempdb].[dbo].[persist_test].id5p

            ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [tempdb].[dbo].[persist_test].id5

        AncOp_PrjEl COL: Expr1004 

            ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [tempdb].[dbo].[persist_test].id5
```

So it appears that all the computed column definitions get expanded out then during the Project Normalization stage all the identical expressions get matched back to computed columns and it just happens to match `id5` in this case. i.e. it does not give any preference to the `persisted` column.

If the table is re-created with the following definition

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.persist_test (
      id            INT NOT NULL
    , id5p          AS (5 * id) PERSISTED
    , id5           AS (5 * id)
);
```

Then a request for either `id5` or `id5p` will be satisfied from reading the persisted version of the data rather than doing the calculation at runtime so the matching appears to happen (at least in this case) in column order.

Comment: FYI this is another case where TF 176 is effective (though undocumented for this usage)